# One click booting OS X to Windows (and back) on bootcamp-ed MBP

Tags: macos, boot

Windows and OS X both run well on my MacBook Pro.

Is there a method to place an alias to "Boot to Windows" that will 'Boot to windows without much more fuss.

I want to replaces the sequence of  'System Preferences' **->** 'Startup Disk' , Select Windows Partition, Press "Reboot", confirm ... on the OS X side, and the similar dance and song in Windows XP with on simple button cleck .. ok, I'd accept or even appreciate one (1!) confirmation dialog...

I know about pressing the command key at boot time .. but I'd rather go and grab some coffee than baby sit a boot process.

---

**EDIT** here's the solution I arrived at thanks to [benjamin-schollnick](https://superuser.com/users/6164/benjamin-schollnick)

I downloaded, unzipped and opened [WinRestart](http://www.rainbowlazer.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/WinRestart.app.zip) in AppleScriptEditor.

It contains two lines of code::

```
do shell script "bless -mount 
   /Volumes/[*BootCampPartition's Name goes here*]/ -legacy -setBoot -nextonly" 
   with administrator privileges
do shell script "shutdown -r now" 
   with administrator privileges
```

I then opened the Finder and navigated to /Volumes (press cotrol-shift-g, then type /Volumes) to find my BootCamp partition's name (StiefelLager , silly German litteral translation af "Boot" and "Camp")  and replaced the **[**BootCampPartition's Name goes here**]** from the script above with that name. My script now reads (2 lines!):

```
do shell script "bless -mount 
    /Volumes/StiefelLager/ -legacy -setBoot -nextonly" 
    with administrator privileges
do shell script "shutdown -r now" 
    with administrator privileges
```

Saving the file to a now name converted it from the 'old' fromat to something current.

Not quite a one click solution (I have to click run, then type my password), but much easier than what I had to do before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is Winrestart...

I reviewed it here...
http://www.schollnick.net/wordpress/2009/02/winrestart-applescript-mini-app-for-automatically-restarting-boot-camp-into-windows/

It's an applescript applet that will ask for your Administrator password, and then restart into windows, but not reset your startup drive.

This way you can boot into windows, play your game, etc....  And then just restart, and it'll automatically reboot back to the Macintosh...

The author's web site:

http://rainbowlazer.com/category/os/boot-camp/

Comment: sounds promising! I'll investigate!

Comment: requires me to install rosetta! Strangeness!

Comment: I was able to load it with the AppleScriptEditor then save it under another name. Will test next.

Comment: +1 and ACCEPT! It Worked!  I'll edit my question and add the steppes I took to make it work! THANK YOU!